# Establishing the n-th order weak derivative.

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-derivatives

Consider $$AC^{n}:=\{f\in{AC}:f^{(k)}\in{AC}, 1\leq k \leq n-1\}$$ where $AC$ stands for the space of absolutely continuous functions.

Now, let $f,g\in{L_{loc}^{1}(a,b)}$ and $$\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\phi(x)dx=(-1)^{n} \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\phi^{(n)}(x)dx$$ for all $\phi\in C_{0}^{\infty}(a,b)$. Show that $f\in{AC_{loc}^{n}(a,b)}$ and $g(x)=f^{(n)}(x)$ a.e. on $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long effort and time I fix the solution of this problem as below.

Consider 
\begin{eqnarray}
F_{0}(x) & = & g(x)\\
F_{1}(x) & = & \int_{a}^{x}F_{0}(t)dt
\\
& \vdots & 
\\
F_{n}(x) & = & \int_{a}^{x}F_{n-1}(t)dt
\end{eqnarray}

Then by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for Lebesgue Integrals (See Theorem 3.35 on p. 106 of [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471317160)) each $F_{i}$ for $i=1,2,3,...,n;$ is locally absolutely continuous. By construction $F_{n}^{(n)}(x)=g(x)$. Now, 
$$
\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\phi(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}F_{n}^{(n)}(x)\phi(x)dx=(-1)^{n}\int_{a}^{b}F_n(x)\phi^{(n)}(x)dx
$$
where we did the usual integration by parts to get the third term from the second and we can do integration by parts there as we have $F_{n}\in{AC_{loc}^{n}}$. Thus, we have 
\begin{eqnarray}
& \int_{a}^{b}F_n(x)\phi^{(n)}(x)dx & = & \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\phi^{(n)}(x)dx
\\
\Rightarrow & \int_{a}^{b}(f(x)-F_n(x))\phi^{(n)}(x)dx & = & 0
\\
\Rightarrow & f(x)-F_n(x) & = & P_{n-1}(x)
\\
\Rightarrow & f(x) & = & P_{n-1}(x)+F_{n}(x) \ a.e. \ on \ (a,b) 
\end{eqnarray}
where $P_{n-1}(x)$ is a polynomial of degree less or equal to $n-1$. Let's call $h(x):=P_{n-1}(x)+F_{n}(x)$ then $f(x)=h(x)$ a.e. on $(a,b)$. As $F_{n}\in{AC_{loc}^{n}}$ then so is $h\in{AC_{loc}^{n}}$. By construction $h^{(n)}(x)=g(x)$ a.e. on $(a,b)$. Hence, we have the required result.